# MYSQL - User database setup

Tags: php, mysql, database, structure

I am trying to properly set up a user database structure and will be using PHP to use the MySQL database. Here is the root of my troubles: There will be several users in one table (called users) and several staff members in one table (called staff). Some 'staff' members work for a couple of 'users'.

I know I could serialize an array with PHP and store that but I feel like that is cop-out.

What is the best solution to this problem? What would my database and table structure look like?

Thanks!
Brandon

Comment: I think you'll want to read up on database relationships - http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Comment: Database design is a very large money maker in the real world.  If you can help it, i would actually keep your db Init to a different file altogether and then just call it once.  I usually just run mysql in a console and build my db there and then when i get what i like, i will just create the associated script.  There is also a command you can do from the terminal.  I actually forget the exact synax.  Something like:  `mysql -u root -Ap < myfile.sql`

Similarly you can log into mysql and just say `source myfile.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is verry simple. Just look at it this way. there are persons, we do not divide them into staff or users (if you want you can declare an attribute if necessery).

So we have one table: **person** (pers#,name,address, staffmember).
We have a second table: **works_for** ((worker_pers#,chief_pers#), this current project).

the # means Key-field.

Sure you will have more than one project so just create a table: **project**(project#,Project Name,...)
and expand the key for **works_for** to (worker_pers#,chief_pers#,project#).

Be free to name the tables in a decent way.

I love databasedesign